# jquery datepicker прибавить к дате месяцы

Tags: jquery, datepicker

есть некая форма, в которой выбирается период оплаты, он может принимать значения от 1 до 24 - это количество месяцев.

так же есть поле datepicker, в котором выбирается дата активации

и есть поле "Окончание периода" - в котором должно посчитаться дата активации + период оплаты.

```
    $('#ID_DATE').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
    minDate: 0,
}).change(function(){
    var period_date = $('#period_id').val();
    var d = new Date();
    period_date = 30*period_date;
    d.setDate($(this).datepicker('getDate').getDate()+period_date); // вот так пытаюсь сделать, но без результата
    $('#ID_PAYMENT_PERIOD_END').val(d);
});
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Я правда не понял в каком формате у вас выбирается дата активаций.
Но если совсем никак, то можете попробовать так:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Тест</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function() {
      jQuery('#btnscl').click(function() {

        var period = jQuery('#period_select option:selected').text();
        var den = jQuery('#data_start_den').val();
        var mes = jQuery('#data_start_mes').val();
        var god = jQuery('#data_start_god').val();
        if ((parseInt(mes) + parseInt(period)) > 12) {
          ++god;
          mes = (parseInt(mes) + parseInt(period)) - 12;
        } else {
          mes = (parseInt(mes) + parseInt(period));
        }

        var itog = den + '.' + mes + '.' + god;
        jQuery("#finish_period").html(itog);

      })
    })
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  Выберите период оплаты:
  <br>
  <select id="period_select">
    <option>01</option>
    <option>02</option>
    <option>03</option>
    <option>04</option>
    <option>05</option>
    <option>06</option>
    <option>07</option>
    <option>08</option>
    <option>09</option>
    <option>10</option>
    <option>11</option>
    <option>12</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <br>Введите дату активации:
  <br>
  <pre>
День:
<input type="text" placeholder="15" id="data_start_den">
Месяц:
<input type="text" placeholder="06" id="data_start_mes">
Год:
<input type="text" placeholder="2016" id="data_start_god">
</pre>
  <br>
  <button id="btnscl">Подсчитать</button>
  <br>
  <br>Итого:
  <div id="finish_period"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

P.S. Код набросал на скорую руку, поэтому просьба сильно не ругаться.
Если захотите его использовать, то советую поставить проверку на количество дней, месяцев и т.д.

Comment: почти, только дата выбирается в datepicker. И месяц должен быть в формате 01,02...,10, 11,12

Answer (score 1):

я бы сделала так: https://jsfiddle.net/5hy10s0c/

```
$(function() {
    $('.period_start').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
        onSelect: function(dateText, instance) {
            var period_end = $.datepicker.parseDate(instance.settings.dateFormat, dateText, instance.settings);
            period_end.setMonth(period_end.getMonth('dd.mm.yy') + 6); //на примере "плюс 6 месяцев", можно заменить это число переменной
            $('.period_end').val(period_end.toLocaleFormat('%d.%m.%y'));
        }
    });
});
```

для полей

```
<input type="text" class="period_start">
<input type="text" class="period_end">
```

Comment: эм...у вас вообще кроме датапикер ничего не работает)

Comment: Это описание работы с датой, разобранное на примере "плюс 6 месяцев", если внимательно вчитаться в комментарий. Ваша проблема, насколько я понимаю, состояла в сложностях прибавления месяцев к выбранной дате. Или нужно было всю работу за вас сделать?

Comment: у вас не заполняется поле period_end

http://joxi.ru/8AnxgZ4sq8aOem

Comment: потому что у вас гугл хром, который не умеет `toLocaleFormat()`. Можно работать с датой другими стандартными методами или добавить глупым браузерам подобие поддержки https://jsfiddle.net/5hy10s0c/1/

Answer (score 0):

дата окончания рассчитывается, как при выборе даты в календаре, так и при изменении периода, также есть предустановка календаря на текущую дату и период в 30дней, смотрите пример ниже.

```
var $sel = $("#period_id"), $picker = $("#ID_DATE"),  $end =    $("#ID_PAYMENT_PERIOD_END")

function selected() {
    var selectedDate = $picker.val();
    var period_date = (+$sel.val() || 1) * 30,
        instance = $picker.data("datepicker"),
        date = $.datepicker.parseDate("dd.mm.yy", selectedDate, instance.settings);
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + period_date);
    date = $.datepicker.formatDate("dd.mm.yy", date, instance.settings);
    $end.val(date)
}
$picker.datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    buttonText: "Дата активации",
    dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy",
    minDate: 0,
    onClose: selected
}).datepicker("setDate", new Date);
$sel.on("change", selected).change();
```

```js
$(function() {

  $.datepicker.regional['ru'] = {
    closeText: 'Закрыть',
    prevText: '&#x3c;Пред',
    nextText: 'След&#x3e;',
    currentText: 'Сегодня',
    monthNames: ['Январь', 'Февраль', 'Март', 'Апрель', 'Май', 'Июнь', 'Июль', 'Август', 'Сентябрь', 'Октябрь', 'Ноябрь', 'Декабрь'],
    monthNamesShort: ['Янв', 'Фев', 'Мар', 'Апр', 'Май', 'Июн', 'Июл', 'Авг', 'Сен', 'Окт', 'Ноя', 'Дек'],
    dayNames: ['воскресенье', 'понедельник', 'вторник', 'среда', 'четверг', 'пятница', 'суббота'],
    dayNamesShort: ['вск', 'пнд', 'втр', 'срд', 'чтв', 'птн', 'сбт'],
    dayNamesMin: ['Вс', 'Пн', 'Вт', 'Ср', 'Чт', 'Пт', 'Сб'],
    dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
    firstDay: 1,
    isRTL: false,
    showOtherMonths: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: false,
    showAnim: 'scale'
  };
  $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional["ru"]);
  var $sel = $("#period_id"),
    $picker = $("#ID_DATE"),
    $end = $("#ID_PAYMENT_PERIOD_END");

  function selected() {
    var selectedDate = $picker.val();
    var period_date = (+$sel.val() || 1) * 30,
      instance = $picker.data("datepicker"),
      date = $.datepicker.parseDate("dd.mm.yy", selectedDate, instance.settings);
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + period_date);
    date = $.datepicker.formatDate("dd.mm.yy", date, instance.settings);
    $end.val(date)
  }
  $picker.datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    buttonText: "Дата активации",
    dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy",
    minDate: 0,
    onClose: selected
  }).datepicker("setDate", new Date);
  $sel.on("change", selected).change();

});
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 12px;
}
.active .ui-state-default {
  background: rgba(102, 255, 102, 1)
}
.active:hover .ui-state-default {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 0, 1)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/sunny/jquery-ui.css" />

<label>Дата активации :
  <input id='ID_DATE'>
</label>
<br>

<label>
  <input id='ID_PAYMENT_PERIOD_END'>Окончание периода</label>
<br>
<label>Период оплаты
  <select id="period_id">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13">13</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="16">16</option>
    <option value="17">17</option>
    <option value="18">18</option>
    <option value="19">19</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="21">21</option>
    <option value="22">22</option>
    <option value="23">23</option>
    <option value="24">24</option>
  </select>
</label>
```

Comment: если выбрать 31.12.2016 и период оплаты 24, то у вас результат 21.12.2018, что не верно

Comment: @Виктор результат считается согласно вашим данным `period_date = 30*period_date;` если нужны месяцы реальные то месяцы и прибавляйте а не дни, смотрите ответ @alenkins